# Can't access jsp anymore after setting up Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I recently added filters using spring security to spring mvc application wich worked before. The filters work great but spring can't find the .jsp files anymore. For instance, I have a jsp in `/autoPA/WEB-INF/views/csvuploadform.jsp` bound to a controller mapped to `/upload`.
When I try to access `/upload`, I have to be authenticated. Once I am, I access to the controller (logs prove it) but I get a 404 and a `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/autoPA/WEB-INF/views/csvuploadform.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SocialServlet'` in logs.

Since nothing changed in my code except the `web.xml`, I assume there is a trouble here, but I can't see where.

Here is the aforementioned file :

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>dev</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SocialServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/social-context.xml         
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SocialServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RESTServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/restapi-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RESTServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

And here is the spring-security.xml file :

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="test" password="test" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

And here is the social-context.html :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


    <import resource="properties/socialProperties.xml" />


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dynamease.web.social" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="com.dynamease.entity.springsocialentities.UserInterceptor">
            <constructor-arg ref="usersConnectionRepository" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Allows users to sign-in with their provider accounts. -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController">
        <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryLocator" />
        <constructor-arg ref="usersConnectionRepository" />
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="com.dynamease.entity.springsocialentities.SimpleSignInAdapter" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>


    <mvc:view-controller path="/signin" />
    <mvc:view-controller path="/signout" />
    <mvc:view-controller path="/choice" />

    <!-- Upload -->
    <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" 
        /> -->
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />


</beans>
```

One of my controllers : `

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload")
public class CSVUploadController {
@Autowired
private DynClassifierCSV csvClassifier;
@Autowired
private DynDirectoryServiceImpl dynDirectoryServiceImpl;

@Autowired
private DynCSVService csvService;

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileUpload.class);

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getUploadForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute(new UploadItem());
    return "csvuploadform";
}
```

}`

Any ideas ?

Comment: how do you resolve the views? http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s05.html

Comment: I got this bean declared in my social-context.xml. As I said, it worked before.
I'm adding the file.

Comment: could you show your controller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the trouble : I replaced `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` by `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing spring-security.xml by adding the line

<intercept-url pattern="/views/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>

so that the /autoPA/WEB-INF/views directory will be available to a user with ROLE_USER role.

Hope that helps